# Can windows phone store apps run in tablet?

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing new windows phone 8.1 
[RT] application working fine , but now my client want to give support to tablet also . Does my application work in tablet or I have to create a universal project  ? 
Please help me out for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7.x or 8.x apps do not run on Windows 8/8.1/10  "out of the box" - you need to either have a universal app, or share your code (for example as a portable class library) to allow it to also run on the desktop variant of the OS.

If you want your app to run on over vendors tablets (such as Android or iOS) there are solutions that allow some code sharing, but again, you're looking at supporting another codebase to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, for tab support I have to create universal app .